# What approach can i take to developing a Desktop application using Web Technologies

Tags: cross-platform, desktop-application, application-design, web-applications

i am wondering if there is any way i can create an app that starts as a desktop application, for personal use for now. and since desktop applications can work with my HDD files which i may want to manage but don't feel secure throwing them onto a web server. but what i think i may want to do in the future is port the app to the web since that is where i think is the future of applications to come. web apps are available everywhere eg. web apps can be used on smart phones etc. facilitate team collaboration etc.

i have looked at some technologies but all seem to have some disadvantages

---

## Adobe AIR 2

### Advantages

- Use of existing web technologies make it easy for me (mainly a web developer) to design and develop applications based on HTML5, CSS3, JS (jQuery, Dojo) which can be ported to a web platform in the future with greater ease
- can access file system

### Disadvantages

- i guess speed maybe an issue
- i may encounter limitations with what can be done in JS (vs languages like C#, Python, Java etc)

---

## C#/F#/WPF/EF/LINQ

### Advantages

- C#/F# powerful languages
- EF/LINQ makes data access very simple
- WPF provides good data binding, styling capabilities

### Disadvantages

- WPF harder to use/learn than what i already know (HTML/CSS/JS)
- WPF abit more complex
- Harder to port over to a web platform (... maybe with a .NET platform its still ok? but i think Open Source PHP/Apache is more widely used)

---

## Silverlight (Out of Browser)

### Advantages

- C#/F# more powerful than JS

### Disadvantages

- complexities of WPF vs HTML/CSS

---

## Mozilla Framework

*i dont know much about this option yet*

### Advantages

- XUL as a layout tool, i guess provides more flexibilities than HTML?
- uses CSS/JS existing web technologies so porting maybe still quite straightforward
- i think it can use native API/Code tho i dont know how it works yet
- in general, i think it will be a more powerful option over adobe air

### Disadvantages

- Architecture of software seems messy, chrome folders etc? i think WPF seems like a much more powerful and elegant option compared to this?

*i have seen QT-Webkit too, but same as Mozilla Framework, WPF seems like a much more powerful and elegant option*

just FYI, i am thinking of building a Project Management/Organizer type application. most parts of it i think it will work on a web platform except i wanted to integrate features like screen capture, managing project files, resources (eg. web site inspirations, resources like fonts, videos, etc). i am also exploring [Adobe XMP](http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/) to add metadata to files (images, videos etc).

Comment: There's a nice example of an Air application called Balsamiq Mockups, http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups, that has good performance.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) or [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/) which are platforms that allow an application to run on the desktop or web. There is also an open-source alternative called [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/) that, like Adobe Air, is also multi-platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [OpenLaszlo](http://www.openlaszlo.org/) which uses flash.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) — it allows building cross-platform desktop apps with web technologies like JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.