# How to improve the look and feel of PyGTK GUI?

Tags: python, pygtk

Can we somehow customize how PyGtk GUI windows look, by for example - changing the color of the title bar, the grey color of the windows, for a rich feel on the lines of Adobe Flex UI?

Comment: Why PyGtk? I'm looking for something more-or-less like what you ask in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610869/web-technologies-in-gui-apps.

Comment: Well, have made a few PyGTK apps already and it serves my purpose of Desktop apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK's way seems to be that the look is a user choice, not a developer choice.

So, the user can change the GTK Theme, and that will affect all gtk apps, including yours.

Take a look at some themes [here](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=100).

Comment: I'm running Pygtk on Windows.. Can we apply the same here?

Comment: Yes. This site offers a windows tool to switch themes: http://gtk-win.sourceforge.net/ I never used it though